# React and Redux: Redux State for Each Action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have component in which there are three subcomponents in it which render data upon loading. In my redux reducer, I have three arrays and a isLoading object. Once data is retrieved it sets isLoading state back to false. My concern is, as we know some data take longer to retrieve than others,
since I have one isLoading object that the other three objects are dependent on, is it best that I create separate reducer files for each array? Or maybe three different loading objects each array having its own loading object name?

//Redux Action File

```
//Get breakfast list
export const getBreakfastList = () => (dispatch, getState) =>{
dispatch({type: LOADING_DATA});
  axios
      .get('/api/breakfastList/', setAuthorizationHeader(getState))
      .then(res =>{
        dispatch({
          type:GET_BREAKFAST_LIST,
          payload: res.data
        })
      })
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch(returnErrors())
      );
};
//Get lunch list
export const geLunchList = () => (dispatch, getState) =>{
dispatch({type: LOADING_DATA})
  axios
      .get('/api/getLunchList/', setAuthorizationHeader(getState))
      .then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data)
        dispatch({
          type:GET_LUNCH_LIST,
          payload: res.data
        })
      })
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch(returnErrors())
      );
};
//Get Dinner List
export const getDinnerList = () => (dispatch, getState) =>{
dispatch({type: LOADING_DATA});
  axios
      .get('/api/getDinnerList/', setAuthorizationHeader(getState))
      .then(res =>{
        console.log(res.data)
        dispatch({
          type:GET_DINNER_LIST,
          payload: res.data
        })
      })
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch(returnErrors())
      );
};
```

//Redux Reducer File

```
const initialState = {
  breakfastList: [],
  lunchList: [],
  dinnerList: [],
  isLoading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case LOADING_DATA:
      return{
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case GET_BREAKFAST_LIST:
      return{
        ...state,
        breakfastList: action.payload,
        isLoading: false
      };
    case GET_LUNCH_LIST:
      return{
        ...state,
        lunchList: action.payload,
        isLoading: false
      };
   case GET_DINNER_LIST:
      return{
        ...state,
        dinnerList: action.payload,
        isLoading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

Comment: `breakfastReducer`, `launchReducer`, and `dinnerReducer` ... each one has it's `Loading`, and `error` state

Comment: Okay. So I’ll go ahead and create different states for each of them. Thank you.